# Moq WCF service doesn't return value

Tags: moq, mspec

My problem is mocked object doesn't return the value it return null instead

My MSpec UnitTest as follows

```
public class With_Fake_Data_Service
{
    protected static Mock<IMProposalWCFService> _fakeDataService;
    protected static FaultContract fault;

    private Establish context = () =>
        {
            _fakeDataService = new Mock<IMProposalWCFService>();

            _fakeDataService.Setup(
                service =>
                service.ReplyToProposal(new ReplyToProposalRequest(Moq.It.IsAny<Proposal>(), Moq.It.IsAny<bool>())))
                            .Returns(new ReplyToProposalResponse( Moq.It.IsAny<bool>(), fault));
            _fakeDataService.Setup(
                service => service.ReplyToProposalEmail(new ReplyToProposalEmailRequest(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), Moq.It.IsAny<bool>())))
                             .Returns(new ReplyToProposalEmailResponse(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), fault));

            _fakeDataService.Setup(service => service.GetAllProposals(Moq.It.IsAny<GetAllProposalsRequest>()))
                            .Returns(() => new GetAllProposalsResponse(new List<Proposal>(){new Proposal()}, fault));

            _fakeDataService.Setup(service => service.GetAllProposals(Moq.It.IsAny<GetAllProposalsRequest>())).Verifiable();

        };
}

 public class When_Testing_HomeController_Index : With_Fake_Data_Service
{
    protected static HomeController _homeController;
    protected static IList<Proposal> _proposals;


    private Establish context = () =>
        {
            _homeController = new HomeController(_fakeDataService.Object);
        };

    private Because of = () =>
        {
            var result = _homeController.Index() as ViewResult;
            _proposals = result.Model as IList<Proposal>;
        };



    private It Should_Have_Called_GetAllProposals_At_Least_Once =
        () => _fakeDataService.Verify(service => service.GetAllProposals(Moq.It.IsAny<GetAllProposalsRequest>()), Times.Exactly(1));
}
```

Inside the Actual Code HomeController Index Method I get response as null when running above unit test

```
 public HomeController(IMProposalWCFService  service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var response = _service.GetAllProposals(new GetAllProposalsRequest());

        if (response.fault == null)    /*Right Here reponse is null when running unit test*/
        {
            var proposals = response.GetAllProposalsResult;
        }


        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
```

Why am i Not getting not null response  in other words why i'm not getting

new GetAllProposalsResponse(new List(){new Proposal()}, fault)

please help

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem its

```
    public class With_Fake_Data_Service
{
    protected static Mock<IMProposalWCFService> _fakeDataService;
    protected static FaultContract fault;

    private Establish context = () =>
        {
            _fakeDataService = new Mock<IMProposalWCFService>();

            _fakeDataService.Setup(
                service =>
                service.ReplyToProposal(new ReplyToProposalRequest(Moq.It.IsAny<Proposal>(), Moq.It.IsAny<bool>())))
                            .Returns(new ReplyToProposalResponse( Moq.It.IsAny<bool>(), fault));
            _fakeDataService.Setup(
                service => service.ReplyToProposalEmail(new ReplyToProposalEmailRequest(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), Moq.It.IsAny<bool>())))
                             .Returns(new ReplyToProposalEmailResponse(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), fault));

            _fakeDataService.Setup(service => service.GetAllProposals(Moq.It.IsAny<GetAllProposalsRequest>()))
                            .Returns(() => new GetAllProposalsResponse(new List<Proposal>(){new Proposal()}, fault)).Verifiable();

        };
}
```

Comment: I recommend [Machine.Fakes](https://github.com/machine/machine.fakes). It makes your code more readable and succinct and gives you better ways to reduce duplication.